# Complex mysql insert

Tags: mysql

I have problems writing one query.
For example, I have table with fields id and name which looks like

```
ID | Name
---+------
1  | John 
2  | Ben
3  | Bob
```

And second table with fields name and somefield. I need to populate this table using data from first one so it looks like

```
name | somefield
-----+-----------
John | blah=1
Ben  | blah=2
Bob  | blah=3
```

So, value of name is name from first table and value of somefield is some phrase like blah=+id value from 1st table.
Is this possible with just mysql ?
I tried to do this using loop and wp wpdb class but wpdb kept throwing some malloc (i think) error after ~ each 30 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into second_table select Name, concat('blah=', ID) from first_table;
```

Warning: This operation will lock `first_table` for the duration of the operation. MySQL needs to do this in order to guarantee consistency during replication. This may be acceptable for a one-time data population but it's probably not advisable to run this regularly on a high traffic production system.

Comment: what if second table have also few fields that should be populated with some static data (not selected from first table) ?

Comment: `insert into second_table (name, somefield, static_field) select Name, concat('blah=', ID), 'static_value' from first_table`;

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT Name,CONCAT('blah=',ID) FROM table1;
```

Comment: Yes, but *why* create this second table?  Better to just use the concatenated `SELECT` result directly from the first table as required (unless cacheing is necessary for performance reasons).

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't bee too difficult. You don't need loops, just use a `INSERT SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO table2(name, somefield)
SELECT name, CONCAT('blah=', id')
FROM table1
```